# pdflatex in a python subprocess on mac

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, pdflatex

I'm trying to run pdflatex on a .tex file from a Python 2.4.4. subprocess (on a mac):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["pdflatex", "fullpathtotexfile"], shell=True)
```

which effectively does nothing. However, I can run "pdflatex fullpathtotexfile" in the terminal without issues, generating a pdf. What am I missing?

[EDIT]
As suggested in one of the answers, I tried:

```
return_value = subprocess.call(['pdflatex', '/Users/Benjamin/Desktop/directory/ON.tex'], shell =False)
```

which fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Benjamin/Desktop/directory/generate_tex_files_v3.py", line 285, in -toplevel-
    return_value = subprocess.call(['pdflatex', '/Users/Benjamin/Desktop/directory/ON.tex'], shell =False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.4//lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 413, in call
    return Popen(*args, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.4//lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 543, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.4//lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 975, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The file does exist and I am able to run `pdflatex /Users/Benjamin/Desktop/directory/ON.tex` in the Terminal. Note that pdflatex does throw a good number of warnings... but that shouldn't matter, and this also gives the same error:

```
return_value = subprocess.call(['pdflatex', '-interaction=batchmode', '/Users/Benjamin/Desktop/directory/ON.tex'], shell =False)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the convenience function, [subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

You don't need to use `Popen` here, `call` should suffice.

For example:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> return_value = subprocess.call(['pdflatex', 'textfile'], shell=False) # shell should be set to False
```

If the call was successful, `return_value` will be set to 0, or else 1.

Usage of `Popen` is typically for cases when you want the store the output. For example, you want to check for the kernel release using the command `uname` and store it in some variable:

```
>>> process = subprocess.Popen(['uname', '-r'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> output = process.communicate()[0]
>>> output
'2.6.35-22-generic\n'
```

Again, never set `shell=True`.

Comment: note: `shell=False` is the default (you don't need to pass it explicitly)

Comment: great post. It helped me a lot for months, but now I have a new issue, I can't specify the output dir, any clue about how to do it?
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468278/how-to-use-output-directory-with-python-subprocess-call-and-macos

Answer (score 1):

You might want either:

```
output = Popen(["pdflatex", "fullpathtotexfile"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
print output
```

or

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["pdflatex" + " fullpathtotexfile"], shell=True)
sts = os.waitpid(p.pid, 0)[1]
```

(Shamelessly ripped from this [subprocess doc page section](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module) ).

Comment: For 1) I needed stdout=subprocess.PIPE, I think, but it still gives the error "OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" although there is and it works in the terminal. For 2), nothing happens when I run it, although sts is set.

Comment: So its complaining that it can't find "pdflatex".  Maybe it's an alias in the shell.  Perhaps you can try the full path to pdflatex.

Comment: Bingo, giving the full path worked, even though it is an alias to pdftex. Although that solves my problem, I prefer sukhbir's syntax. Thanks for your help.

Comment: On Python 3.5+, use `subprocess.run(["pdflatex", "fullpathtotexfile.tex"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`.