# How do you use pdflatex in Python?

Tags: python, pdflatex

I am trying to compile a .tex file in a Python script using pdflatex. The command `pdflatex filename.tex` works when I run it from the command line on Windows. However, attempting to run `os.system("pdflatex filename.tex")` just spits out `1` into the Python console and does not compile a pdf. I've also tried putting in the full file path similar to [this person solved their problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524098/calling-pdflatex-from-a-python-script) but the same thing happens. Similarly, `subprocess.call(['pdflatex', 'filename.tex'])` just outputs a 1 and does not do anything.

It seems someone else has encountered the same problem in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230926/pdflatex-in-a-python-subprocess-on-mac), but on Mac instead of Windows. (But regardless of the operating system, they didn't find an answer.)

Why might this be happening?

**EDIT:** I've just discovered a solution. The script runs successfully (using the `os.system` approach) when I run the .py file *using the command line*. Previously I was attempting to run the script from RStudio, both using `reticulate::source_python(filename)` and also line-by-line via the `reticulate` REPL. Seems like the problem may actually be coming from R's reticulate package rather than anything to do with Python.

Fortunately RStudio has a terminal window so this doesn't end up being too inconvenient!

Comment: Is `pdflatex` in your system path? Have you tried using the absolute path to the `pdflatex.exe` executable? Are you running your python script in the same directory as `filename.tex`? If not, does the absolute file path have spaces? The macOS question you linked does seem to have an answer that worked for them.

Comment: What exactly is the "system path" and how would I check that? Also, how would I go about finding the path of pdflatex.exe? Would it be in my MiKTeX folder? I can find a pdflatex folder in there but no exe file. 

I'm running the script in the same directory, and there are no spaces.

Comment: 1. [Windows system path](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+system+path). If you can run `pdflatex -v` from any folder and get an output, then `pdflatex` exists in your system path. 2. It should be somewhere in your miktex folder. Is there a bin folder inside pdflatex? Just use Windows to search for pdflatex.exe inside your miktex folder

Comment: I do get an output, though it's saying `pdflatex did not succeed`, with the logs mentioning `optionError="unknown option"`. However there's good news, since I managed to get it working! See the edits to the main post. I think the problem may actually have come from R rather than anything else.